# Merge/combine three variables by ID in one dataset

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I have one dataset, with five variables: ID, A, B, C, D. Some IDs are repeated more than one, therefore it makes my dataset larger than it supposed to be (n=3600). Right now I have something like (Table 1), and I would like to see the (Table 2):

[image]

So, basically, combine answers of the variables A,B,C into one by their ID, and make only one row per ID (like in the case of ID2).

Also, for the variable D, I would like to have a logical response, as in the case of ID2. Once ID2's variables (A,B,C)combined, if any of these variables had 'Attended' response for variable D, then overall, for the ID, it should be 'Attended'.

I apologize if my questions were too simple, I tried to look up from other people's questions and googled as well, but most responses were to merge two datasets into one by their IDs. I hope to get your thoughts, and thank you so much in advance! Any help/thought is appreciated!

Yours,
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youd didn't provide an example ready to use, so with:

```
> Table1
## A tibble: 5 x 5
#     ID A     B     C     D           
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       
#1     1 yes   <NA>  yes   Not Attended
#2     2 yes   <NA>  <NA>  Not Attended
#3     2 <NA>  yes   <NA>  Not Attended
#4     2 <NA>  <NA>  yes   Not Attended
#5     3 yes   <NA>  <NA>  Not Attended
```

You can do, using the tidyverse:

```
Table1 %>% gather(k,v,-ID) %>% filter(!is.na(v)) %>% distinct %>% spread(k,v)
```

And get:

```
## A tibble: 3 x 5
#     ID A     B     C     D           
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       
#1     1 yes   <NA>  yes   Not Attended
#2     2 yes   yes   yes   Not Attended
#3     3 yes   <NA>  <NA>  Not Attended
```

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for the reply. I tried to simplify my question and provide an example with variables A,B,C, but my dataset contains more than 3600 observations so it is difficult to put them all together. Anyway, I did replicate your codes with the packagaes dplyr and tidyr, but I got an error: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (3347, 3632), etc.   In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped

Comment: @MS G I saw the problem when writing my answer : if you have two lines with the same ID and the same variable filled, it doesn't work. You have two options : either retain the last occurence (group_by will help) or have some kind of preference (factors will help together with group_by) : I couldn't decide for you.. Please provide a small extract with repeated answers for a same ID and showing the class of the columns. And please provide the expected result. As recommended in SO, please use dput for that (not a screenshot).